# Koma Remove Page Number from Title Page: Graphicx Misbehavior

Tags: page-numbering, includegraphics

I copied the preamble from one document to another. Now I'm getting a front matter page number on the titling page. I tried adding `\thispagestle{empty}` before `\maketitle`, after `front matter` and after `\maketitle` without results. I tried adding `\pagenumbering{gobble}` in the same places, but this caused all page numbering to disappear.

The `graphicx` demo option yields this behavior, so you do not need the graphic I'm using, i.e.,

```
\usepackage[demo]graphicx
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,BCOR=10mm,headlines=2.5]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{moresize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% TITLE PAGE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 \setkomafont{title}{\normalcolor\bfseries}


\begin{titlepage}
%\thispagestyle{empty} %didn't work  \pagenumbering{gobble} removed all page numbering in document




\title{
\centering
       % \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}\par
        \vspace{4\baselineskip}
        {\HUGE{Companies Law}\par}
        \vspace{2\baselineskip}
      %  {\Large{A Tool for Finding The Law}\par}
        \vspace{4\baselineskip}
        {\large\textsc{edited by\\[.5em]The Editor}}
        \vfill
       \includegraphics[width=1cm]{andaluslogo.png}\par 
        {\em Andalus Publishing 2022}
     
        }
\end{titlepage}

\lowertitleback{
{\Large

\textit{Guidebook}

©2022 The Publisher


}
} % end of lowertitleback  \Large increases the font on this backtitle page




\maketitle

\mainmatter

\lipsum{1-5]

\end{document}
```

Perhaps there is a way to remove the page number from the title page that I am missing?

I found the problem: if I use `graphicx` package, a page number is added to the title page.

If I don't use it--or perhaps another package--I can't add a graphic to the title.

Is there an alternative to the `graphicx` package which does not exhibit this behavior?

Additionally, the `graphicx` package creates an unwanted additional page before the title page.

If I use a larger paper size (a4) the issue disappeared as well. That would make you think that the graphic was oversized, but the [demo] option suggests that is not the issue.

Comment: I am afraid your MWE *is* kind of useless: We don't have the images you're referring, and it doesn't even compile (there is no `\textsc` without specifying a different font, e.g.) That said, have you tried using `\pagenumbering{gobble}` and subsequently turning it back on again with `\pagenumbering{arabic}` or similar?

Comment: You won't "incur the wrath of the powers" by providing an MWE that doesn't show the behaviour, it is only utterless senseless. How should anyone be able to help with this info? You will have to find the code in the preamble or before the titlepage which triggers the change.

Comment: I found that the culprit is the `graphicx` package and so amended the question accordingly. I found this by slowly adding packages to the example. Since the culprit is the `graphicx` package, is there an alternative package which will not cause this behavior?

Comment: @Ingmar: I edited the question. The `graphicx` package is part of the problem. @Ulrike

Comment: remove the \title from the title page, add something like `\title{A Tool for Finding The Law}` to your preamble.

Comment: @Ulrike: you mean delete the entire `titlepage` environment? Then I lose all the other data. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean only the \title command. It doesn't belong there, its function is to store a title.

Comment: This solves the pagination problem but creates a new, separate title page with the text added to `\title{}`. Otherwise, the file won't compile and throws this error: ` LaTeX Error: No \title given.`

Comment: This solves the pagination problem but creates a new, separate title page with the text added to `\title{}`. Otherwise, if the `\title` command is removed (but the `begin{titlingpage} retained,  the file won't compile and throws this error: ` LaTeX Error: No \title given.`